# Clone a private repo on a computer with multiple GitHub accounts

Tags: ssh, git, github

I'd like to be able to use different GitHub accounts for different repos on my computer.

But when I try cloning a private repo from the 2nd account, I get this error:

```
$ git clone git@githubpersonal:2nd-github-account-username/redacted.git

Cloning into 'redacted'...
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

---

In `~/.ssh/config` I have the SSH key for my second GitHub account set up, which is `id_rsa_personal`. `id_rsa` is the one the other GitHub account uses, and it works.

```
Host githubpersonal
    Hostname github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_personal
```

## What I've tried so far

At first I thought it might be an issue with the `user.name` and `user.email` in my `~/.gitconfig` not matching the account. So I added

```
[includeIf "gitdir:~/projects/"]
    path = ~/projects/.gitconfig
```

...and made a `~/projects/.gitconfig` with the other name & email. That did not work.

Then I read that you need to be in an existing git repository for that includeIf to work, which doesn't make sense before you clone the repo, so I just switched my global gitconfig:

```
$ git config --global user.name "<2nd-github-account-username>"
$ git config --global user.email "<2nd-github-account-email>@gmail.com"
```

Still no luck. `git config --get user.email` and `user.name` show the expected values.

I'm not sure where else to look from here.

Comment: Since it is a private repo, the most likely cause is that the account you're using doesn't have access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the specified keypair is not being honored, try enabling the `IdentitiesOnly` option. The client might be using the wrong key from ssh-agent.

Test using `ssh githubpersonal` – make sure the server greets you with the expected GitHub account name.

The `user.*` settings are not used for authentication. The Git protocol has no authentication of its own, only the one provided by SSH (or HTTPS).

Comment: ssh githubpersonal did indeed greet me with the wrong username, and adding IdentitiesOnly to the githubpersonal ssh config did indeed fix the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would create PAT tokens for each account and follow the below syntax to clone the repo.

git clone https://<your_username>:<your_PAT_token>@<fullpath.git>

If you want to manage the git repo as per account owner, then setup ssh keys in ~/.ssh/config' or follow the answer -> user1686